# Ruby on Railsでプレビュー機能を実装したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

登録前にプレビュー表示を確認して登録を実行するといった画面を作成したいと思っています。
登録機能は既に実装済みであとはプレビュー機能を実装したいと思っています。

```
  <%= f.textarea_frame(:hoge, :placeholder => t('.input.hoge')) %>
  <%= f.text_frame(:hoge_id, :placeholder => t('.input.hoge_id')) %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, :class => "control-group", :style => "position:relative") do
    f.submit(:confirm => true)
  end %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, :class => "control-group", :style => "position:relative") do
    submit_tag "プレビュー", name: "preview_button"
  end %>
```

[サブミットボタンを複数にして](http://www.maepachi.com/blog/entry/131)
controlerで処理を分けようとしたのですがnameの部分がパラメータに渡ってこず分岐できません。
submitメソッドはオーバライドされていて、それが原因なのか何か似たような事象がありましたら教えて頂きたいです。

```
<%= button_tag :type => "submit",
  :name => "preview_button",
  :class => "btn btn-hoge",
  :"data-confirm_message" => t('.save_hoge_message') do
    content_tag(:i, "", :class => "icon-hoge")
  end %>
```

button_tagで別ボタンを作っても駄目でした。

バージョン情報
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2)

Comment: controller で params を受けている箇所も貼ってみてください。または、params を puts して確認してみてください。
form の書き方を間違えているか、controller を間違えているか、これだけだと判断が難しいです。

Comment: 遅くなって申し訳ありません。paramsは以下のような値が入っています。

{"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "hogehoge"=>{"message"=>"ああああああ", "hoge_id"=>""}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"hogehoge"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params.keys.include?("preview_button")
```

controllerで取得できました。